# How to run linux terminal commands on windows?

Tags: node.js, linux, windows, electron, child-process

I'm not sure how to ask, but I'd like run the 'bash' command on windows 10 so that some linux commands run later. I'm using the framework Electron and the Child Process.

```
var os = require('os')
var exec = require('child_process').exec
if (os.platform() =='win32'){
    var cmd_win = 'bash'
    exec(cmd_win, function(error, stdout, stderr){
        console.log(error)
    });
}
```

The code snippet gives "Error: Command failed: bash". Does anyone know why? And can you help me? I hope you understood my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initialize the WSL subsystem, you must launch a (hidden) Bash *console window* *in the background*, which doesn't work if you execute `bash.exe` *directly* - it works with neither `exec` nor `execFile`.

The trick is to get the shell (`cmd`) process that Node.js spawns to launch `bash.exe` *without blocking*, which, unfortunately, isn't easy to do: `start` cannot be used, because `bash.exe` is a *console* application and therefore makes `start` act *synchronously*.

The solution is to create an aux. VBScript file that launches `bash.exe`, which itself can be invoked asynchronously via `wscript.exe`. Note that the Bash console window is launched *hidden*:

```
var os = require('os')
var exec = require('child_process').exec
if (os.platform() === 'win32') {
  var cmd_win = '\
    echo  WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application").\
      ShellExecute "bash", "", "", "open", 0 > %temp%\launchBashHidden.vbs \
    & wscript %temp%\launchBashHidden.vbs'
  exec(cmd_win, function(error, stdout, stderr){
      if (error) console.error(error)
  });
}
```

Note that the aux. VBScript file `%temp%\launchBashHidden.vbs` lingers between invocations. Cleaning it up after every run would require more work (you can't just delete it right away, because `wscript`, due to running asynchronously, may not have loaded it yet).

Answer (score 0):

By default, `exec` will use `cmd.exe` to execute commands in windows. What you may be looking for is the `shell` option specified in [the docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback).

> `shell` Shell to execute the command with (Default: '/bin/sh' on UNIX, 'cmd.exe' on Windows, The shell should understand the -c switch on UNIX or /s /c on Windows. On Windows, command line parsing should be compatible with cmd.exe.)

```
const os = require('os')
const exec = require('child_process').exec

if (os.platform() === 'win32') {
  exec('ls', {shell: 'path/to/executable.exe'}, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err)
      return
    }

    console.log(stdout)
  })
}
```

Comment: The OP's intent is to launch `bash.exe` _itself, without arguments_ (to launch it in the background so as to initialize the WSL subsystem, if I understand correctly), not to pass _commands_ to it, so in principle the default shell (`cmd`) should be fine, as should using the slightly more efficient `execFile()` be.
However, neither method works with this specific executable (`bash.exe`).

Answer (score -1):

I have found a short way to do that that is :

- Install git on your computer
- Add `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` to your path variable.
  and check whether you can run linux commands in cmd.